# Creating CSV file in python which will list all files from a directory with a server name alongside

Tags: python, linux, csv, server, ip

I am currently trying to figure out how to create a CSV file in python, which will list all files from /logs category alongside with server name by SSH.
The problem is, whenever I start my script,I get something like:

```
server, machine
IP;file1 file2, file3 file4 etc
IP2;file1 file2, file3, file 4 etc.
```

When in my CSV I need something like this:

```
server, machine
IP;file1
IP;file2
Ip;file3
IP;file4
IP2;file1
IP2;file2
IP2;file3
etc...
```

With my current code i am not sure how to start with this problem
The relevant fragment looks like this:

```
SLIST = path to csv from which i took IP
CMD2 = 'ssh %s ls  /opt/syslog/logs'

def mloop():
     f = open('out.csv', 'a')
     columnTitleRow = "server, machine\n"
     f.write(columnTitleRow)

     for i in csv2hash(SLIST):


       if i.get('IP'):
          r = getoutput(CMD2 % (i['IP']))

       server = i['IP']
       machine = r
       row = server + ";" + machine + ";" + "\n"
       f.write(row)
     f.close()
```

and as you can see... "r" gets all files from logs folder, the problem is I don't have any idea how to put each file separately to csv.

Answer (score 0):

Use python in-build library `csv`

```
import csv

output_file = open('outputfile.csv', 'wb')
fieldnames = ['server', 'machine']
writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

def mloop():
    ...
    ...
    server = i['IP']
    machine = r
    row = {'server': server, 'machine': machine}
    writer.writerow(row)

output_file.close()
```

Read more about [Python csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Well it's a good way to list them all however it still do the same as my code. Which is basically:
IP1: file1
file2
file3
file4
etc...

While i need to iterate files and do csv like:
IP1:file1
IP1:file2
IP1:file3

Comment: @sever I didn't get your problem?

Comment: Yes, because right now the output i am getting is:
`server;machine`
`10.10.10.10; file1file2file3file4file5file5file6file7`
`10.10.10.11;file1file2file3file4file5...`

however i want to do this like this:
`server;machine
10.10.10.10;file1
10.10.10.10;file2
10.10.10.10;file3`

Comment: @Sever use `writer.writerow(row)` according to your need